# what;s wrong with my sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

what;s wrong with my query ...

i get the error message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. mail_time FROM ibc_messages m , ibc_msg_queue q  AND m . id = q . msgid  AND q' at line 1

```
SELECT distinct q.msgid, q.mail_time, m.status,
FROM ibc_msg_queue q , ibc_messages m
WHERE q.mail_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND q.msgid = m.id
ORDER BY q.msgid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the comma after your third column

```
SELECT distinct q.msgid , q.mail_time,m.status FROM
```

Comment: Good eyes, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma before the "FROM" clause

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant comma (`,`) before your `FROM` keyword. Just remove it, and you should be fine:

```
SELECT distinct q.msgid , q.mail_time,m.status
FROM ibc_msg_queue q , ibc_messages m
WHERE q.mail_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND q.msgid = m.id ORDER BY q.msgid
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma in there:

YOURS:

```
SELECT distinct q.msgid , 
       q.mail_time,
       m.status, 
FROM ibc_msg_queue q , ibc_messages m
WHERE q.mail_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
  AND q.msgid = m.id 
ORDER BY q.msgid
```